# How to have different Group Policy at different sites map user's Redirected Folders on SBS 2008?

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, dfs, folder-redirection

I have a DFS setup between my two locations and there are a few employees that move between them. Can I have a GPO at each location that changes their Redirected Folders to the local server?

I have the contents of the folders replicated.

- Server1: Windows SBS 2008
- Server2: Windows Server 2008

`//domain.local/files/users/FolderRedirects` is the DFS name

`//server1/RedirectedFolders` is the share on Server1

`//server1/RedirectedFolders` is the share on Server2

Our would it be better to have the users Redirected Folders mapped to the DFS directly?

These user are not changing locations rapidly so the files have plenty of time to replicate. A user might leave one location and 30-60 minutes later arrive at the second location. Usually they would work one day at location 1 and maybe another day at location 2.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that mapping the redirected folders to DFS would be the better way to go. I might also suggest configuring Offline Files for the redirected folders as well.

Comment: I think we already have the offline files configured.